# Unable to inspect WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, ios-simulator

I'm having trouble using the safari Web Inspector with a WKWebView running in the iOS simulator. The simulator doesn't appear in the Develop menu, it has worked previously.

I'm using XCode 8.1, Simulator 10.0 and Safari 10.0.1 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue here, and i tried:

1. make sure the simulator `setting-safari-advanced-web inspector` opened
2. reboot the simulator
3. if the simulator still not exist the menu, relaunch safari

may be you can just try the 3rd step, the simulator came back after step 3.

Comment: Do you mean turn that feature on in the Settings app on the simulator? If so, yes I've made sure that is turned on, still no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I've kept the simulator open and relaunched safari as well as keeping safari open and relaunched the simulator

Comment: I was having this issue as well, with the same software setup. Step 3 cleared it up for me.